# Read from a Slave with SPI

Tags: c++, avr, atmega, atmelstudio

I'm working with Atmega328p and I'm coding a program which can read and write from microcontroller and memory chip,

I tried to write tab and it was written correctly, but when I want to read the tab from the memory chip, I receive number 255, I could not specialize this error!

Can someone help me?

```
uint16_t read_SPI (uint16_t address){
    Slave_select;
    SPDR= address;
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
    Slave_deselect;
    return (SPDR);
}


void write_SPI (uint16_t address, uint16_t byte){
    Slave_select;
    SPDR=byte; 
    while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF)));
    //address=SPDR; 
    /*SPI_tradeByte(0x02);
    chip_send16BitAdress(address);
    SPI_tradeByte(byte);*/
    Slave_deselect;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually you send byte per byte (`unsigned char`) over SPI as the SPI data register `SPDR` is just 8 bits wide, [see datasheet](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-42735-8-bit-AVR-Microcontroller-ATmega328-328P_Datasheet.pdf) page 224.

Also you generally use one function for sending and receiving, the following is a typical implementation of that for both receiving and sending. The function is from [here](http://maxembedded.com/2013/11/the-spi-of-the-avr/) where the SPI is very well explained.

```
//Function to send and receive data for both master and slave
unsigned char spi_tranceiver (unsigned char data)
{
   // Load data into the buffer
   SPDR = data;

   //Wait until transmission complete
   while(!(SPSR & (1<<SPIF) ));

   // Return received data
   return(SPDR);
}
```

A big difference to your code is, that you're setting the `SPDR` to an `uint16_t` value so that the register overflows.

---

Further you have to send the right commands to your memory chip. You have to select a direction `READ` or `WRITE` and also address a memory cell by sending the `ADDR`. If the address room is larger than one byte you have to send separate bytes.

You have to look it up in the datasheet of your memory controller. [Here](http://hades.mech.northwestern.edu/index.php/Interfacing_PIC_with_SPI_memory) is also a nice example that could help.

---

**Edit #1:**

Concerning to the [datasheet of your memory controller](http://www.fujitsu.com/us/Images/MB97R803A-DS411-00003-1v0-E.pdf) you have to consider the following points:

**1.
READ (datasheet page 19):**

To read from the chip you have to send:

```
0x03            = 0b00000011:          8 bit  READ command
0x0000 - 0x07FF = 0bXXXXXAAA AAAAAAAA: 16 bit ADDRESS (5 upper bits don't care)
```

Then you will receive:

```
0x0000 - 0xFFFF = 0bDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD: 16 bit DATA
```

**2.
WRITE (datasheet page 19):**

To write to the chip you have to send:

```
0x02            = 0b00000010:          8 bit  WRITE command
0x0000 - 0x07FF = 0bXXXXXAAA AAAAAAAA: 16 bit ADDRESS (5 upper bits don't 
0x0000 - 0xFFFF = 0bDDDDDDDD DDDDDDDD: 16 bit DATA
```

**3.
Memory layout (datasheet page 8):**

The user memory area goes from 0x0000 to 0xA6F.

**4.
Use the SPI information register (datasheet page 20):**

> In Serial communication mode, if the LSI encount
>   ers an error when executing a READ/WRITE command,
>   the error codes will be stored in th
>   e SPI Error Information Register.
>
> ```
> Bit       15 14 13 12 11 10 9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1  0
> Function  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  0  | ERROR* |
> * :  ERROR
> b1000 : Low voltage detection
> b0100 : Write NG
> b0010 : Read NG
> b0001 : NG because RF occurred
> b0000 : Finished successfully
> ```

---

The datasheet is very detailed about the communication and also there are timing and communication diagrams. Send the commands as I said but byte per byte because the `SPDR` register is just 8 bits wide. Do it like the function I provided and it should work.

Comment: Thank you @Andre Kampling, i'm trying to work as u showed to me but i get  usually 255 output value

Comment: @D.G: What is meant by sending tab? Do you send tab character 0x09?

Comment: i mean that i want to write a tab of value in my chip memory then read this tab from microcontroller

Comment: @D.G: I don't get what you want to say. What is a tab of value. Could you please show how you call your functions respectively provide more informations?

Comment: this is my main funtion:

Comment: and after i have

Comment: @D.G: Please edit your question and don't post that as answer... Also add exact output or the code where you output if it is not the debugger.

Comment: @D.G: Further if you're sending you don't send an address where to place your data. Also you don't send the right commands your memory chip needs. What is your memory chip? Look in that datasheet...

Comment: @D.G: On page 12 are all commands also in that sheet is written that you have to change to SPI mode first. Read the manual, send the right commands...

Comment: @D.G: I  completed my answer due you posted more information before. You deleted them again as it  were down voted. The problem was, that you posted it as an answer. You should edit your question to provide all information needed.

Comment: @Andre.Kampling, thank you for your forward, i'm trying to fetch on the problem in my code, i think it's linked with the datasheet of the chip

Comment: yes it works thank you, the error was in the SPI library, i did't ,mention SPI << 1 for the micro-controller i just mention the chip select